# Comparing non optional value leads to error

Tags: swift, firebase

I am on point where I gotta compare non optional value with nil. But I can't do it because Xcode says:

> Comparing non-optional value of type 'Int' to nil always returns false

So I created Struct and then made variable: `var products: [Product] = []`

How I am able to compare it with nil?:

```
if products[indexPath.row].snusPortions == nil
        {
            cell.snusPortionsAmountLabel.text = "N/A"
        }else
        {
            cell.snusPortionsAmountLabel.text = String(products[indexPath.row].snusPortions)

        }
```

I've assigned values to them like this:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Brand").queryEqual(toValue: brandName)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists(){

                let enumerator = snapshot.children

                while let thisProduct = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot
                {
                    print(thisProduct.value) // So I may see what the data is like and know how to extract it

                    // Chances are you'd have to create a dictionary
                    let thisProductDict = thisProduct.value as! [String:AnyObject]

                    let productName = thisProductDict["Products"] as! String

                    let snusPortions = thisProductDict["PortionsCan"] as? Int

                    let productObject = Product(snusProductTitle: productName, snusNicotine: snusNicotine, snusPortions: snusPortions!, snusFlavor: snusFlavor, snusWeight: snusWeight!, snusShippingWeight: snusShippingWeight, snusProductImageURL: productURL)
                    self.products.append(productObject)
                    print(self.products)

                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()  

            }
        })
```

This is Product struct:

```
struct Product {
    var snusProductTitle: String

    init()
    {
        snusProductTitle = ""
    }

    init(snusProductTitle: String){

        self.snusProductTitle = snusProductTitle
    }

}
```

While testing it says `snusPortions` is `nil` but I said to make it "N/A" if it is nil, why?

Comment: Show the definition of Product, please.

Comment: So Product's `snusPortions` is an Int. It can never be `nil`.

Comment: I know that this value doesn't exist in Firebase database. But if it doesn'. Then how I say on label that it is "N/A" then?

Comment: See my answer below. You are showing two unrelated pieces of code.

Comment: I hope you don't mind - I rolled back your last edit, so that my answer makes sense in relation to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are confusing yourself between the *local variable* `snusPortions` and the Product *property* `snusPortions`.

In your Product definition, the property `snusPortions` is an Int. It can never be `nil`. Hence, in this code:

```
if products[indexPath.row].snusPortions == nil
```

... this Product's `snusPortions` will never be `nil`, and we will never set the text to "N/A".

Now let's look at your other code:

```
let snusPortions = thisProductDict["PortionsCan"] as? Int
```

This is a *completely different* `snusPortions`. It *can* be `nil`, namely, if `thisProductDict` lacks a `"PortionsCan"` key or if its value is not castable to Int.